# Add a button to the mobile theme to open a question in the iOS/Android apps

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, android-app, mobile-web

I often find SO answers in Safari and I would like to open them in the App by tapping a button on the site, like Twitter does at least on iOS.

Would it be possible to implement such a feature please?

By pressing the button with a phone you open the user site in the Twitter App:

Comment: Doesn't android already have that feature?

Comment: As you can see I don't use android. 2. It's not a duplicate I'm not talking about downloading the app but opening the current question in app.

Comment: Which that request would do. If you have downloaded it, it opens the question in the app. If you haven't, you can download it

Comment: At least, that's what I had intended by my request!!

Comment: Sorry didn't read close enough, questions are really very similar